# How to make a request with a header using ajax to a service which is redirecting to another

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-headers, redirect

I'm making a request from Chrome using ajax to a service. 
My request contains a header.
And that service is redirecting.

**This is my Ajax Code:**

```
  $.ajax({ url: "http://192.168.0.1:8080/App1/api/sample", headers: {Test: "Hi        Test"}, success: function(data) { console.log(data); } });
```

In IE it is working fine, but in chrome it is not working when I'm adding any header to the ajax call.

**Error Message:**

It is prompting that request is redirected to the 2nd service and prompting a error message that "***XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://192.168.0.1:8080/App1/api/sample`. The request was redirected to '`http://192.168.0.1:8080/App2/api/sample`', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight***".

FYI: `http://192.168.0.1:8080/App1/api/sample` is the first url to which i am doing a AJAX request and `http://192.168.0.1:8080/App2/api/sample` is the 2nd URL to which it is redirecting to.

I have applied filter to add headers for CORS. like Access-Control-Allow-Origin as *, Access-Control-Allow-Headers as Test, Access-Control-Allow-Methods as "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" to both the project(means both the services).

And the services are normal java services.

**So, my question is, how to call a service (which is redirecting) using ajax and the request contains header.**